# Looking For JMF h.264/rtp encoder&decoder plug-in

Tags: java, h.264, rtp, jmf

I'm using jmf for transmitting video stream,JPEG_RTP codec works, but rtp packet sizes too big. so I am looking for h.264_RTP encoder/decoder plugin for jmf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an h.264 encoder source code
[http://pt.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_h264avcjavaenco/releases/?file_id=1304126](http://pt.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_h264avcjavaenco/releases/?file_id=1304126/%22here%22)